# PL/SQL - global variable isn't avaible in all Sessions

Tags: oracle, plsql, functional-programming

I have a comprehension question with using global variables in PL/SQL packages. 
I have declared a global variable in the spec of an package.

--> g_processid       VARCHAR2 (30);

In the body of the same package I initialize the variable in a procedure which is used first 
in my process. This works well. The result of the variable isn't null.

After that the main session starts a another procedure for 16 times. So I have
16 parallel jobs doing the same thing.

Snippet:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. p_process_count
      LOOP
         DBMS_JOB.submit (job            => v_job_sid,
                            what           =>    p_jobname
                                              || '('
                                              || i
                                              || ','
                                              || p_process_count
                                              || ');',
                          next_date      => SYSDATE,
                          no_parse       => FALSE
                         );
        ....
         v_job_counter := v_job_counter + 1;
         v_tab_kuba_jobs (v_job_counter) := v_job_sid;
         COMMIT;
         IF  p_process_count > 0
         AND i = 1 THEN
             -- 60 Sekunden Pause
             DBMS_LOCK.sleep (180);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
```

In the procedure which is used by the threads I want to use my global variable. 
I call the variable in this way: . 
My problem is that the variable in the Thread is empty.

Maybe it's because the processes aren't using the same instance of my package. 
What do I have to do to make my variable usable for all my sessions.

Thank you for your recommendation. I appriciate any kind of advise.

Best regards
Jörn

Comment: you can store your variable in a table, and make a function that returns this value. This is not an efficient solution, but it migth helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of global application contexts you can use to share data amongst sessions

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/app_context.htm#CIHFJHCG

There is a very good example here http://technology.amis.nl/2009/01/21/oracle-database-cross-session-data-cache-introducing-the-globally-accessible-database-context

Basically you use

1) `create or replace context global_cache using cache_mgr ACCESSED globally;`

2) Write a package with a procedure that uses `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT( 'global_cache','my_key' , 'my shared value');`

3) Set the value using the package procedure

4) Use `sys_context('global_cache','my_key')` to retrieve the value in the other session

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer. Yes, global variable or not, it is not possible to get access to a variable of another process in a normal way because every process uses its own memory etc.

Actually I solved the problem by storing the data in a table. Every process has to initialize the value by himself. Global applicatopn context sounds really interessting.
Thanks.

After posting my question I found this good explanation:

### Package Instantiation and Initialization

When a session references a package item, Oracle Database instantiates the package for that session. Every session that references a package has its own instantiation of that package.

When Oracle Database instantiates a package, it initializes it. Initialization includes whichever of the following are applicable:

- Assigning initial values to public constants
- Assigning initial values to public variables whose declarations specify them
- Executing the initialization part of the package body